# How can i set style to QLayout

Tags: css, python-2.7, pyqt4

i'm trying to add a stylesheet to my script by using css, everything looks fine but i can't set a style to a QLayout.
How can i change it's background color
this is example of what i'm done.

```
def main_style(self):
    self.setStyleSheet("""
        .QVBoxLayout{
            background-color: #616161;
        }

        .QMenuBar{
            background-color: #212121;
            color: #f5f5f5;

        }

        .QMenu{
            background-color: #212121;

        }

        .QTextEdit{
            background-color: #424242;
            color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px #9e9e9e solid;
        }
        """)
```

The program is running with no errors
and all changes happen except the QVBoxLayout it's still the default

Comment: When you say you can't set a style, what do you mean? what happens when you try to execute this code?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Do you just not see the expected change?  More information is needed.

Comment: all changes are done as i like except the QVBoxLayout it's still default

Comment: the program is running with no errors

Comment: A `QLayout` is not a paint device, so it cannot have a background colour.

Comment: i can't set a background color to QLayout??

Comment: @AhmedAbdeldaim. No. A layout is not rendered - it just controls the positions and sizes of the items it contains. To be useful, it must be contained by a widget - which *is* a paint device, and therefore *can* have a background colour.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Thanks a lot for your help :)